# ARM __clear_cache equivalent for iOS devices

Tags: ios, arm

I'm porting a library to the iPhone which makes a call to `__clear_cache`. A little research digs up this [nice explanation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120314112445/http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/141-caches-and-self-modifying-code/) of what it does.

The article lists the library functions for Linux, Windows and even Android. I don't suppose there is an equivalent for iOS devices? Or some other workaround I can implement?

Comment: As iOS is a *NIX-based platform, and you compile code with apple's version of GCC (LLVM), you should just be able to make a function call to `__clear_cache(beg, end)`.

Comment: You're right! If I switch to LLVM-GCC instead of Apple LLVM Compiler (which I think now uses clang) I can build OK. This has solved my problem in this instance, I wonder what the solution would be if I couldn't revert to the old compiler.

Comment: Ok, well, I added the comment as an answer, please be sure to up-vote and accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As iOS is a *NIX-based platform, and you can compile code with apple's version of GCC (LLVM-GCC 4.2), you should just be able to make a function call to `__clear_cache()`, like this:

```
extern void __clear_cache(char *beg, char *end);

__clear_cache(beg, end);
```

Note that this will NOT work with `Apple LLVM Compiler 3.1`, only with GCC for some odd reason.